# JS Object Field Extraction from an Array

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array, immutable.js, nested-object

This is my Product

```
[
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "size": "S",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 8999,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 69,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400"
        ],
        "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecb",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecc",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 4
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecd",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 13
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "size": "XL",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199ad",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "SHERPA TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 10199,
      "rating": 2,
      "sales": 18,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-alt6-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=2000&hei=1125"
        ],
        "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199ae",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199af",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199b0",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 33
          },
          {
            "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199b1",
            "symbol": "XL",
            "stock": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "size": "S",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199ad",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "SHERPA TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 10199,
      "rating": 2,
      "sales": 18,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-alt6-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/163650044-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=2000&hei=1125"
        ],
        "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199ae",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199af",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199b0",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 33
          },
          {
            "_id": "607285bf70ce0f0660f199b1",
            "symbol": "XL",
            "stock": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "size": "M",
    "product": {
      "_id": "6072b314af87143c5cd39b32",
      "title": "Levi's Premium",
      "name": "EX-BOYFRIEND SHERPA TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "women",
      "price": 12099,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 50,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/361370034-front-pdp?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/361370034-back-pdp?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=2000&hei=1125"
        ],
        "_id": "6072b314af87143c5cd39b37",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "6072b314af87143c5cd39b38",
            "symbol": "XS",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "6072b314af87143c5cd39b39",
            "symbol": "M",
            "stock": 33
          },
          {
            "_id": "6072b314af87143c5cd39b3a",
            "symbol": "XL",
            "stock": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "size": "M",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 8999,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 69,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400"
        ],
        "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebf",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec0",
            "symbol": "XS",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec1",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec2",
            "symbol": "M",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec3",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 33
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec4",
            "symbol": "XL",
            "stock": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "size": "M",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 8999,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 69,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340134-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340134-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340134-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400"
        ],
        "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec5",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec6",
            "symbol": "M",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec7",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 44
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec8",
            "symbol": "XL",
            "stock": 1
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec9",
            "symbol": "2XL",
            "stock": 44
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42eca",
            "symbol": "3XL",
            "stock": 44
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "size": "L",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 8999,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 69,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400"
        ],
        "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebf",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec0",
            "symbol": "XS",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec1",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec2",
            "symbol": "M",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec3",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 33
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec4",
            "symbol": "XL",
            "stock": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 16,
    "size": "S",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 8999,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 69,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340144-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400"
        ],
        "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebf",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec0",
            "symbol": "XS",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec1",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec2",
            "symbol": "M",
            "stock": 10
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec3",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 33
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ec4",
            "symbol": "XL",
            "stock": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Each Product has **quantity**, **size**, **product**. Each **Product** has **_id** and **variant** and Each **variant** has **_id**.
I want a new const where I have

- **quantity**
- **size**
- **product._id**
- **product.variant_id**

Like This

```
{
  "productId": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
  "variantId": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebf",
  "size": "S",
  "quantity": 16
}
```

[or this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afNJF.png)

I want to **setOrder** which is an *array of Objects* and each Object contains *productId*, **variantId**, **size**, **quantity** of all **products**

I'm using React. This is my code what I have been able to do so far. I want to do this Immutable way

```
function getOrderInfo(product){

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(product,null,2))

        product.forEach( (item, index) => {        
            const selectedBasketItem = product.find((item, ind)=> ind === index ) 
            const currentProductId = {productId:selectedBasketItem.product._id}
            const currentVariantId = {variantId:selectedBasketItem.product.variant._id}
            const quan = {quantity:selectedBasketItem.quantity}
            const size = {size:selectedBasketItem.size}
            const payload = {...currentProductId, ...currentVariantId, ...size, ...quan}
            
            
            setOrder({...order,...payload})

        })
        
    }
    getOrderInfo(basket)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating quite a few objects and then spread them again, which I don't see any use for. For starters maybe merge them.

```
const currentProductId = {productId:selectedBasketItem.product._id}
const currentVariantId = {variantId:selectedBasketItem.product.variant._id}
const quan = {quantity:selectedBasketItem.quantity}
const size = {size:selectedBasketItem.size}
const payload = {...currentProductId, ...currentVariantId, ...size, ...quan}
```

is the same as

```
const payload = {
  productId:selectedBasketItem.product._id
  variantId:selectedBasketItem.product.variant._id,
  quantity:selectedBasketItem.quantity,
  size:selectedBasketItem.size
}
```

The line
`const selectedBasketItem = product.find((item, ind)=> ind === index )`.
shadows `item` in it's inner function. It is also uneccessary, because `selectedBasketItem` and `item` (the one of the upper scope) are the same object!. It basically loops through the products and for each product it finds, it searches the product.

---

Now let's dive into the actual task:

The Immutable.js way would be to use [Records](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) or [Maps](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) for your two objects.
First define a Record somewhere global:

```
const OrderProduct = Immutable.Record({
  productId: null,
  variantId: null,
  size: null,
  quantity,
});
```

you can then create records:

```
products.forEach((item) => {
  const mutableData = {
      productId:selectedBasketItem.product._id
      variantId:selectedBasketItem.product.variant._id,
      quantity:selectedBasketItem.quantity,
      size:selectedBasketItem.size
  };
  const payloadRecord = OrderProduct(mutableData);
  // ... do something
});
```

if `setOrder` expects an array (or maybe even better a `Immutable.List`), you could use `Array.map` to convert from product object to OrderProduct:

```
const arrayOfProducts = products.map((item) => {
  // build payloadRecord as above
  return payloadRecord;
}
// To turn it into an Immutable.List: 
// const myList = Immutable.List(arrayOfProducts);
setOrder(arrayOfProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
products.map((item) => {
let { size, quantity, product } = item;
let { _id, variant } = product;
return {
size,
quantity,
productId: _id,
variantId: variant["_id"]
};
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).